# jQuery conflicts when iframe used to insert web form

Tags: jquery, iframe, conflict

I am having to iframe a form into a development site.  The form will be hosted on the same domain but i am not able to edit any of the contens of the document that contains the form.

My issue is that the document that contains the form is using a very old version of jQuery and was wondering if this is going to cause conflicts with the vaersion (latest) on the  parent site.

Comment: Would you like to make jQuery actions inside the iframe, from the parent page? This is not possible.

Comment: Yes you can if it is same domain.  YOu need to use the .contents() method to find the iframe content.  Am performing several DOM manipulations and attaching event handlers as we speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no conflicts, the two documents are completely separate. It is possible to interact between the two DOMs, the actual script cannot see each other. This makes `iframe`s ideal for sand-boxing.

Comment: +1 for the prototyping suggestion. That's actually the only use I've every had for iFrames.

Answer (score 2):

In scope of DOM, your two different jQuery instances won't be in conflict between your parent frame and the iFrame content. This is not to say you cannot have conflicting javascript as it pertains to your browser objects, but if your behaviors are only document related, you should be fine. Your methods and properties won't cross contaminate between multiple source frames.

Comment: Thanks to all for the peace of mind.  @65Fbef05 - i only accepted kim3er as she was first.

Comment: She beat me by a minute! lol, It's alright - I'm glad I could help.